# Replace a method for usage only in a particular unit tests in Scala

Tags: scala, scalatest

Is it possible to replace a method only used in a particular unit tests in Scala using version 2.11 and scalatest 3.0.4?

This is my scenraio:
I have the method

```scala
import java.security.SecureRandom
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex

class KeyHasher extends Serializable {

  // getSalt returns a random number that servers as salt for the actual hash algorithm  
  def getSalt(length): String = {
    val salt: Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](length)
    secureRandom.nextBytes(salt)
    Hex.toHexString(hashedKey)
  }

  def getEncodedKey(actualKey: String): String = {
  ...
  val salt = getSalt() 
  ...
  return applyHash(salt) // apply a hash algorithm using a salt
  }

}
```

For a particular unit test I would like to ensure that the method getSalt returns a constant, not random number.

I know, I could use an additional input Parameter (testFlag) in the getEncodedKey method or a global variable in the getSalt method to get a solution for this. However, I wanted to know if there is a way do not touch the getEncodedKey and only implement something in one unit test.

Comment: Can you show more code? Where does `getSalt` come from? Is it in the same class as `getEncodedKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to just create a trait like `SaltGenerator` and then, implement the one used by your method, this will allow you to create a `SatlGenerator` which returns a constant while testing.

For example:

```
trait SaltGenerator {
  def getSalt(length): String
}

class KeyHasher(saltGenerator: SaltGenerator) {...}
```

Then, while writing your test, just create the generator that returns a constant:

```
val saltGenerator = new SaltGenerator {
  def getSalt(length): String = ???
}
```

While you may be able to find a way to mock an existing method, that is always tricky and is hard to maintain. If you don't want to update your code, another way is to receive the `SecureRandom` as a constructor argument but that won't be that simple on the test side to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class that extends your original class and only override the methods that you want to, something like:

```
class DummyClass(x: Int) {
  def doSomething(): String = "xyz"

  def doSomethingElse(): Int = x * 2
}

class DummyClass2(x: Int) extends DummyClass(x) {
  override def doSomething(): String = "abc"
}

val a = new DummyClass(3)
val b = new DummyClass2(3)

println(a.doSomething())     // xyz
println(a.doSomethingElse()) // 6
println(b.doSomething())     // abc
println(b.doSomethingElse()) // 6
```

([see live here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ucv81evgQXOSKNSWJMPCWg))

or:

```
class DummyClass(x: Int) {
  def doSomething(): String = "xyz"

  def doSomethingElse(): Int = x * 2
}

object DummyClass2 extends DummyClass(3) {
  override def doSomething(): String = "abc"
}

val a = new DummyClass(3)
val b = DummyClass2

println(a.doSomething())     // xyz
println(a.doSomethingElse()) // 6
println(b.doSomething())     // abc
println(b.doSomethingElse()) // 6
```

([see live here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gqOGteAZRBCXreVWEMEUzg))

This isn't ideal though... you have encountered one of the major problems with random code - it's hard to test. One solution could be to put your random generator in a new class/object/whatever and extend/inject it, so you can override it in tests. Something like this:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import scala.util.Random

class Generator {
  def rand = Random.nextInt()
}

class Dummy @Inject()(num: Int, gen: Generator) {
  def doSomething(): Int = num * gen.rand
}

// ---------------
//   ACTUAL CODE
// ---------------

val generator = new Generator
val x = new Dummy(3, generator)
println(x.doSomething()) // something
println(x.doSomething()) // something different

// ---------------
//    TEST CODE
// ---------------

val nonRandomGenerator = new Generator {
  override def rand: Int = 4
}
val y = new Dummy(3, nonRandomGenerator)
println(y.doSomething()) // 12
println(y.doSomething()) // 12
```